# Center of mass of a solid hemisphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mass

So I was just playing around with center of mass derivations, trying to find the center of mass of objects using methods not used in the 'typical' derivation.

Coming to a solid hemisphere, I found that I can divide the hemisphere into a stack of elementary half-discs (sharing the same diameter along a particular diameter of the hemisphere).

Accordingly, I know that the center of mass of a half-disc is at a distance of $\mathrm{\frac{4R}{3\pi}}$ from its center, along the perpendicular to its diameter.

I effectively have a semicircular ring of radius $\frac{4R}{3\pi}$ that passes through the center of masses of the half-discs. In other words, the hemisphere of radius $R$ is equivalent to a half-ring of radius $r=\frac{4R}{3\pi}$.

I also know the formula for the center of mass of a half ring, which is $\mathrm{\frac{2r}{\pi}}$ along the axis perpendicular to the diameter of the ring. This gives me a center of mass at a distance of $\frac{8R}{3\pi^2}$.

This is obviously not correct. In fact, a bit of inspection tells me that if I reversed the constants in '$r$' (i.e. $r=\frac{3\pi R}{4}$), I would get the correct expression for the center of mass $\left(\frac{3R}{8}\right)$. I'm not sure if this is just a coincidence or not.

I feel I'm making a really stupid blunder. Is that really the case, or is my approach is wrong in the first place?

Comment: Hemisphere cannot be divided into half disks.

Comment: Where do you think is the center of the half ring?

Comment: Also,  you consider the ring as having uniform mass?

Answer (score 1):

It so happens that I just assigned a HW problem (What is the frequence of small oscillations of a hemisphere resting (inverted) on a smooth plane?) that requires determining the location of the CM as the first step.

The CM is at
$$
z_{CM} = \frac{\int r^2dr\int d\cos\theta\; (r\cos\theta)}{\int r^2 dr \int d\cos\theta} 
= \frac{3}{8} R
$$
when measured from the center of a sphere that contains the hemisphere. Obviously, the CM is along the line of symmetry (here called the $z$-axis) of the hemisphere.

If I want to think in terms of stacking disks I write
$$
z_{CM} = \frac{\int dz (R^2-z^2)z}{\int dz (R^2-z^2)} 
= \frac{3}{8} R
$$
which is of course the same result. I don't quite know what you mean by equivalent half disk,

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is an elegant derivation. As I mentioned, however, I know the 'typical' approach while finding the center of mass. I wanted to know if my approach (stacking a bunch of half-discs sharing a common diameter to create an equivalent half-ring and subsequently finding the COM) is correct or not.

Comment: @C_Lycoris see addendum